# JAVA - hibernate- creating a new query in a DAO

Tags: java, hibernate

Hi I have some problem to create a dynamic query with hibernate :

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<EnvironmentConfiguration> findEnviromentProperty(String environment) {
    EntityManagerHelper.log(
            "finding property EnvironmentConfiguration instances", Level.INFO,
            null);
    try {
        final String queryString = "(select e.name as environment,\n" + 
                "       SUBSTRING_INDEX(ec.name ,'.',-1) as property,\n" + 
                "       ec.value \n" + 
                "from pkca_test_db.ENVIRONMENT e, pkca_test_db.ENVIRONMENT_CONFIGURATION ec\n" + 
                "where e.ID=ec.ID_ENVIRONMENT      \n" + 
                "and e.name=" + environment +"= :propertyValue )\n" + 
                "union \n" + 
                "(select b.name  as environment,\n" + 
                "       SUBSTRING_INDEX(bc.name ,'.',-1) as property,\n" + 
                "       bc.value \n" + 
                "from pkca_test_db.ENVIRONMENT b, pkca_test_db.ENVIRONMENT_CONFIGURATION bc\n" + 
                "where b.ID=bc.ID_ENVIRONMENT  \n" + 
                "and b.id=1) ;";
        Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery(queryString);
        query.setParameter("propertyValue", environment);
        return query.getResultList();
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        EntityManagerHelper.log("find all failed", Level.FATAL, re);
        throw re;
    }
}
```

this value e.name=" + environment +"= :propertyValue must by a parameter. Is there any mistake in the query's syntax?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried if it works on a regular SQL? https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/f?p=590:1000

Comment: `"and e.name=" + environment +" and "+ environment +"= :propertyValue )\n"` should do the trick. You can't chain checks like x=y=z. You need to chain them with `AND` or `OR`

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what do you try to do there. The query in your case will be something like that `...e.name=*value*= :propertyValue...`.

Probably what do you want to do is 
`...e.name=" + environment + " union`.

Comment: I think he wants to have something like t.name='valueOfEnvironment=propertyParameter'